# New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment command giving error

Tags: powershell

When I run the  New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment and pass a JSON parameter file, I get the below error:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 2:29:31 PM - Resource Microsoft.Sql/servers 'qsservername' failed with message '{
  "code": "15021",
  "message": "Invalid value given for parameter Login. Specify a valid parameter value.",
  "target": null,
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "15021",
      "message": "Invalid value given for parameter Login. Specify a valid parameter value.",
      "target": null,
      "severity": "16"
    }
  ],
  "innererror": []
}'
At M:\Azure\Azure Scripts\Something\somethingdeploy.psm1:63 char:4
+    New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGro ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

However, when I run the same command but pass the parameters instead of the file, it works fine. any ideas what I may be missing?

Comment: I've just hit the same issue - did you end up resolving it?

Comment: My parameter file was missing an essential parameter required to log in which was causing this error,

Answer (score 7):

For me, this error happened when I tried to run ARM templates with the existing SQL Azure instance resource. The problem was that in the template I specified a DB username which didn't match the admin username of the existing instance. It's ok to update the password, but the username has to remain the same for the life of SQL Azure instance,

Comment: Can confirm that the scenario you describe, triggers the same error